# ¿Cómo hago para no perder los datos de una variable en funciones?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa en Python sobre un menú con el cual agrego los datos de una empresa y luego cuento con contadores la cantidad de empresas que ingresaron.

Tengo una funcion menuprincipal()
y otra submenu()

En el submenu() tengo 3 contadores , al finalizar la carga yo quiero volver al menuprincipal() pero pierdo los datos de los contadores y cuando vuelva al submenu() estaran en 0 nuevamente...

¿Es posible mantener los datos del contador al llamar otra funcion? Como en este caso menuprincipal()

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código?

Comment: ¿podrías darme el código para poder ayudarte? De todos modos te paso esta liga, espero haber sido de ayuda por el momento
https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/parametros-por-referencia/#:~:text=Te%20dir%C3%A9%20por%20qu%C3%A9%3A%20el,objetos%20utilizando%20tuplas%20o%20listas.

Comment: Respuesta corta: "si, es posible". Para la respuesta larga, haría falta ver el código, pues el error está allí.

Answer (score 2):

En Python las funciones son objetos, y como cualquier otro objeto, pueden tener *atributos*. Estos atributos se pueden accesar usando la notación usual de `objeto.atributo`, que en este caso sería `funcion.atributo`.

Dada una función cualquier, puedo crear sus atributos por simple asignación:

```
def una_funcion():
    pass

una_funcion.titulo = "Una función"
print(una_funcion.titulo) => Una función
```

Tener que inicializar los atributos de una función por fuera no resulta muy conveniente. Si ocupamos la función `hasattr(objeto, nombre)` podremos chequear si el atributo existe, y si no, inicializarlo dentro de la misma función.

Veamos como ejemplo una función que lleva un contador:

```
def funcion():
    if not hasattr(funcion, 'contador'):
        funcion.contador = 0
    funcion.contador += 1
    return funcion.contador
```

En cada invocación la función primero chequea que el atributo `contador` exista; en caso contrario lo inicializa a cero.

Luego de incrementar el contador en uno, lo retorna.

El contador mismo (`funcion.contador`) es accesible y modificable como cualquier otro atributo de algún objeto. En el siguiente código mostramos como producir dos secuencias distintas con la misma función:

```
#   Imprimir la secuencia 1 .. 10
for i in range(10):
    print(funcion())

funcion.contador = 100 # Modificar directamente el contador

#   Imprimir secuenica 101 .. 110
for i in range(10):
    print(funcion())
```

produce:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Datos():
    contador = 0

def main():
    def menu():
        Datos.contador = 5

    def imprimirContador():
        print(Datos.contador)

    imprimirContador()
    menu()
    imprimirContador()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Puedes crear una clase (en el ejemplo `Datos()`), en la que incluyes una variable. Así puedes acceder a ella desde cualquier función. Simplemente escribe el nombre de la clase, un punto y el nombre de la variable: `Datos.contador`.

Por supuesto, también puedes asignarle un nuevo valor (`Datos.contador = 5`).

El resultado es:

```
0
5
```

Comment: Pero tu solución es equivalente a tener variables globales, y así te evitas tener que entrar en programar clases, si el op no conoce ese aspecto. Y si vas a programar clases, entonces yo ya usaría métodos de la clase para implementar las funciones, y así comparten datos a través de los atributos del objeto